# Blocking Spam referral traffic - better to redirect or throw up a 403 error?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, bots, spam, referrals

I'm testing out a plugin on a Wordpress site to prevent referral traffic. The default setting is a redirect to google.com. I can override this and display a 403 error instead.

Do you see any advantage with one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read when researching how to deal with this issue, most of the referral 'spam' you are getting in google analytics doesn't actually come from hits to your site, but instead it is done by spammers exploiting google's analytics code, by using random tracking IDs, and they up end up using your ID too.

Having said that, I don't think a wordpress plugin can do anything to prevent that kind of spam as they don't ever reach your site, and I believe the vast majority of referral/analytics spam being done currently is using the method mentioned above.

So the best way to get rid (or at least largely reduce the amount) of referral spam you're getting is to set filters within your google analytics dashboard. Even the methods for that are constantly changing, as google keeps improving that service, but here's two fairly recent articles that may help you configure those:

https://www.distilled.net/resources/quick-fix-for-referral-spam-in-google-analytics/
http://www.shivarweb.com/4635/filter-analytics-spam/

Comment: Thanks for your input. There are two problems with this referral spam. One is server load. The other is getting accurate Google Analytics readings and filtering out the referral spam. I am more concerned with server load. The way I understand the way the plugin works is that is essentially compares the visitor to the spam list. If they are on the spam list they get denied access. Similar to a firewall. So, they can't hammer the server over and over. I am just not sure why one would want to serve them a 403 vs redirecting them to another URL-I just used Google as an example. It could be any URL